# building a 32 bit application on 64 bit debian 6 (Make)

Tags: makefile, 64-bit, cmake, debian, 32bit-64bit

i wanted to build an application in 64 bit mode, here is my Makefile.am
i use debian 6 amd64 for 64 bit
and this make file is for a project call theforgottenserver which is for tibia (game)

```
    noinst_PROGRAMS = theforgottenserver

CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -pipe
AM_CXXFLAGS = $(XML_CPPFLAGS) $(OTSERV_FLAGS) $(LUA_CFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS)\
$(MYSQL_FLAGS) $(SQLITE_FLAGS) $(PGSQL_FLAGS) $(PROFILER_FLAGS)\
$(OPTIONAL_FLAGS) -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -Wall -Wextra -Wno-strict-aliasing

theforgottenserver_LDADD = $(LUA_LIBS)

if USE_MYSQL
MAYBE_MYSQL = databasemysql.cpp databasemysql.h
endif
if USE_SQLITE
MAYBE_SQLITE = databasesqlite.cpp databasesqlite.h
endif
if USE_PGSQL
MAYBE_PGSQL = databasepgsql.cpp databasepgsql.h
endif
if LOGIN_SERVER
MAYBE_LOGIN = gameservers.cpp gameservers.h
endif
if OT_ADMIN
MAYBE_OTADMIN = admin.cpp admin.h
endif

theforgottenserver_SOURCES = account.h actions.cpp actions.h $(MAYBE_OTADMIN) \
    allocator.cpp allocator.h baseevents.cpp baseevents.h beds.cpp \
    beds.h chat.cpp chat.h combat.cpp combat.h condition.cpp condition.h \
    config.h configmanager.cpp configmanager.h connection.cpp connection.h \
    const.h container.cpp container.h creature.cpp creature.h \
    creatureevent.cpp creatureevent.h cylinder.cpp cylinder.h database.cpp \
    database.h databasemanager.cpp databasemanager.h $(MAYBE_MYSQL) \
    $(MAYBE_SQLITE) $(MAYBE_PGSQL) depot.cpp depot.h dispatcher.cpp \
    dispatcher.h exception.cpp exception.h fileloader.cpp fileloader.h \
    game.cpp game.h $(MAYBE_LOGIN) globalevent.cpp globalevent.h group.cpp \
    group.h house.cpp house.h housetile.cpp housetile.h ioban.cpp ioban.h \
    ioguild.cpp ioguild.h iologindata.cpp iologindata.h iomap.cpp iomap.h \
    iomapserialize.cpp iomapserialize.h item.cpp item.h itemattributes.cpp \
    itemattributes.h items.cpp items.h luascript.cpp luascript.h \
    mailbox.cpp mailbox.h manager.cpp manager.h map.cpp map.h monster.cpp \
    monster.h monsters.cpp monsters.h movement.cpp movement.h \
    networkmessage.cpp networkmessage.h npc.cpp npc.h otpch.h otserv.cpp \
    otsystem.h outfit.cpp outfit.h outputmessage.cpp outputmessage.h \
    party.cpp party.h player.cpp player.h position.cpp position.h \
    protocol.cpp protocol.h protocolgame.cpp protocolgame.h \
    protocolhttp.cpp protocolhttp.h protocollogin.cpp protocollogin.h \
    protocolold.cpp protocolold.h quests.cpp quests.h raids.cpp raids.h \
    rsa.cpp rsa.h scheduler.cpp scheduler.h scriptmanager.cpp \
    scriptmanager.h server.cpp server.h spawn.cpp spawn.h spells.cpp \
    spells.h status.cpp status.h talkaction.cpp talkaction.h teleport.cpp \
    teleport.h templates.h textlogger.cpp textlogger.h thing.cpp thing.h \
    tile.cpp tile.h tools.cpp tools.h town.h trashholder.cpp trashholder.h \
    waitlist.cpp waitlist.h waypoints.h weapons.cpp weapons.h vocation.cpp \
    vocation.h
```

when i try to use 'make' command it gives me this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `allocator.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output 
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `exception.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
make[1]: *** [theforgottenserver] Error 1 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/theunkown/Downloads/TFS' 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Remove the `allocator.o` and `exception.o` files and try again. If you get the same error, paste the exact command line used to compile `allocator.cpp` and `exception.cpp`.

Comment: i've fixed it my adding -m64 to the optional flags and it worked

Comment: @TarekAdel Kindly add your answer to the "answers" section and accept it to mark this effectively "closed." It helps those who come here via google, too :)